# Notify multiple people simultaneously?

Tags: support, comments

Is it possible to `@` multiple people simultaneously? I tried to use `@` for the second time, but auto completion doesn't show up for the second `@`, so not sure about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not, and you'll get an error if you try to submit a comment with multiple targets:

[image: Only one additional @ user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified]

The error is reminding you that there's no need to @target the post owner; they get a notification no matter what. So if you @target a commenter, both the commenter and the post owner will get a notification, but you can't ping two commenters